# Receiving wrong params when navigating to a route

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using `react-navigation` in my react native app.

In two different places I a have button to navigate to a route. One button also sends params and one button does not:

```
<Button onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('profile', { user: 'test' }) }} title="test" />

<Button onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('profile') }} title="test" />
```

In profile route I have a `componentWillMount` function to set state according to received params:

```
componentWillMount() {
  const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;

  if (params && params.hasOwnProperty('profile')) {
    this.setState({
      profile: params.profile
    });
  }
}
```

The problem is that if I press the first button (the one that sends params), then navigate back to the same view and press the second button, I'm still receiving the same params, even though the second button isn't sending any!

Answer (score 0):

Not by my computer so I can't test. 
But what if you navigate with the second button first? Do you still get the params passed to the page?
Also you dont mention what type navigation you sre navigating to. A stack, drawer or tab. Add some more info and I'll try to come back to you tomorrow. 
But my impression is that you are navigating to the same page the second time and that page is already mounted. And hence not rerendered. Have you tried with componentDidUpdate an passing no variables on the second button?

This is the change I suggest in our discussion:

```
if (params && params.hasOwnProperty('profile')) {
  this.setState({
    profile: params.profile
  });
else if (params && params.hasOwnProperty('profile')){
  this.setState({
    profile: null
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm using drawer navigation. If I click the second button first it works as intended, i.e. no data is passed.

Comment: Ok, Think I know what causes the problem. First time you set the state for the profile screen when this screen mounts for the first time. 
Then you navigate back without resetting the the navigation. 
When you navigate to the screen again. The componentWillMount is not triggered and hence the variable user is still defined.

Instead of setState you could just use the code from the componentWillMount to the render function.

Also it might be a good idea to do some console.log('Did update') to see if the code inside the componentWillMount is triggered or not.

Comment: When I do `console.log(params)` from `componentWillMount` and render function they both log the same object...

Comment: ok, if componentWillMount is logged when going to the profile  screen second time. Try to add

 else if (params && !params.hasOwnProperty('profile')) {
    this.setState({
      profile: ''
    }); Just after you if statement. Sorry for bad formatting. If it works or if you dont get it I'll update my answere....

Comment: What's even stranger if I pass an empty object to second button I'm still receiving the old object...

Comment: Setting `this.props.navigation.state.params = null;` in `componentWillUnmount` fixes the issue but this looks like a hack to me...

Comment: But did you try to add my else if{}() suggestion? Added that suggestion to my answere above.